# Expo Location Error: Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Not authorized to use background location services

Tags: react-native, location, expo

I want to get the user's location even when the App is in the background. I am using expo-location and expo-task-manager in the following manner:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  Platform,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from "react-native";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";
import * as Location from "expo-location";

const STATUSBAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === "os" ? 20 : StatusBar.currentHeight;
const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = "background-location-task";

export default function TestingGround({ navigation }) {
  const onPress = async () => {
    const { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === "granted") {
      await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          height: 50,
          width: 300,
          backgroundColor: "red",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
        onPress={onPress}
      >
        <Text>Enable background location</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    paddingTop: STATUSBAR_HEIGHT,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
    console.log("error", error);
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    // do something with the locations captured in the background
    console.log("locations", locations);
  }
});
```

On press, I get the error: Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Not authorized to use background location services.
Location services are enabled. I don't understand what I need to do.

I also added the following to my App.json but with no success:

```js
 "android": {
     ...
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"]
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIBackgroundModes": [
          "location",
          "fetch"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a week of battling it I finally found a solution. It turns out that the reason I am getting this error is simply because I am running this code on Expo which does not allow background location fetching. There is nothing wrong with the code, all I had to do was to build a standalone App (expo build:android) and the standalone version of the App worked just fine and could fetch background location

I also passed an extra parameter to my Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync which increased the effectiveness of background-location fetching and actually allowed me to visualize that the App is fetching the background-location via a notification like this:

```js
const onPress = async () => {
  const { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
  if (status === "granted") {
    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
      timeInterval: 3000,
      foregroundService: {
        notificationTitle: "BackgroundLocation Is On",
        notificationBody: "We are tracking your location",
        notificationColor: "#ffce52",
      },
    });
  }
};
```

I hope this helps someone out there and don't hesitate to contact me for further assistance on this matter.

Comment: I noticed that background location works fine inside Expo Go on iOS its just Android that seems to fail for me.

Comment: Well, I managed to get it working on an Android device for both Expo and Standalone App. You can create a new question and share your code and tag me I will help you

Comment: @ProffMushianaMulweli I just created a question; think you might be able to give me a hand?

Comment: @shyguy189540 yes of course, where is the question?

Comment: @ProffMushianaMulweli I ended up getting the background location running in the app, but it tracks the user's location in perpetuity, I.e., when the app is closed out completely, it is still running and tracking location in the background. Any thoughts how to make it only track the user in the background when the app is engaged?

Comment: @shyguy189540 please create a new question and tag me I will assist you